# Approximate size of the "hut" object observed from the Yutu-2 lunar rover?

Tags: the-moon, cnsa

News sources (for example, [the Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/china-rover-mystery-house-dark-side-moon-b1970567.html), [the South China Morning Post](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/science/article/3158627/chinas-lunar-rover-yutu-2-mission-investigate-mystery-object-far), [RT](https://www.rt.com/news/542331-mystery-hut-far-side-moon/), [and Newsweek](https://www.newsweek.com/china-yutu-2-lunar-rover-spots-cube-house-moon-1656322)) have reported recently on the observation from the [Yutu-2 lunar rover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yutu-2) of a "hut" object or "funny-shaped rock". Its distance from the rover is said to be 80 metres.

Approximately how large is it?

---

[image: potentially square-shaped "hut" rock on the Moon as seen from the Yutu-2 lunar rover]

(image source: https://twitter.com/AJ_FI/status/1466677831929405443)

Comment: Do you have a link to any of the news sources?

Comment: Edited: four links added.

Comment: Thanks! "Its origin and purpose - still a total mystery."

Comment: Idea: Match the image to a portion of a panorama, and scale the width/circumference by the 80 metres radius times 2pi. Good quality Yutu 2 panorama here, but I don't immediately see the match: https://moon.bao.ac.cn/www/plviewer/moon.html (though some of the horizon is missing)

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys - Thanks for this. I couldn't find a match either, but it may be possible to match [these features](https://i.imgur.com/5soyJqJ.jpg). Perhaps an image showing the object with the image's overall angle of view marked is also publicly available somewhere.

Comment: The interpretation of this silhouette as a cube reflects the human visual bias towards rectilinear objects. If you zoom in and enhance the image, the object's true curvilinear nature  will be revealed: a pair of buttocks.

Comment: We are being "Mooned"

Comment: @Woody another *faux* rectangles [Does the luminous blue shockwave from the RS-25 engine appear to be rectangular?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16926/12102)

Comment: @OhOh For sure. And have a close look at the rock at 8:00 from the buttocks. It is definitely a "Burning Schoolhouse"  https://www.archangelfireworks.com/burning-schoolhouse.html

Comment: @uhoh I found the FOVs, see below.

Comment: @KeithMcClary excellent, now need to find the original image to see if it is 4:3 or 1:1 format. What's being shown in the popular press is neither and so probably zoomed & cropped.

Answer (score 4):

**The width of the "funny-looking rock" is no more than about $6.0$ metres.**

The fact that the field of view in the image shown cannot be wider than $360°$ allows us to calculate an approximate maximum possible width. The item takes up approximately $1/84$ of the width of field, so if the width of field represented $360°$ then the item would be about $(2\pi \times 80 \text{ metres}) \ / \ 84 = 6.0$ metres wide.

If the field of view is $360n°$, with $0<n\leqslant1$, then the item's approximate width is $6.0n$ metres. Examples: if the field of view is $60°$, the item's width is about $1.0$ metre; if it is $120°$, about $2.0$ metres.

Comment: Is the "80" in the calculation the distance to the object, as mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes - I will edit.

Comment: Considering that all the rocks in the image have shadows that project towards bottom/left, the angle is **way** less than 360. more like << 60 degrees, possibly even something like 30. Making the rock about exactly 0.5m wide.

Comment: [on the rover are the Panoramic Camera (PCAM),... the Visible and Near-Infrared Imaging Spectrometer (VNIS)](http://epizodyspace.ru/bibl/inostr-yazyki/planetary-and-space-science/2018/Jia_et_al_The_Chang-E-4_Mission_Planetary_and_Space_Science_in_press_(2017).pdf) FOV 19.7x14.5 and 6x6 degrees respectively. How big is the bun?

Answer (score 3):

The so call hut rock observed by Yutu 2 is apparently another [yutu](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-10386183/Mystery-hut-Moon-rabbit-shaped-rock-scientists-reveal.html)!

> 'The "mysterious hut" as tall as the Arc de Triomphe turned out to be very small when approached,' they said in the update.
>
> 'The drivers were a little disappointed. Just as everyone was lost, a driver stared at the enlarged picture and covered his mouth and exclaimed: "Gosh! This is... Yutu!"'

It's a rock in the shape of a crouching rabbit! ... With rabbit food and droppings to complete the scene.

[image]

[image]